# Zoom to Box examples on https://bl.ocks.org do not work properly with Internet Explorer

Tags: d3.js

**Description of Bug:** Instead of zooming to fit the constraints of the bounding box, it's zooming to the size of the entire browser.

**Browser Not Working On:** Internet Explorer

**Versions of Browser Tested On:** 11

**Examples Not Working**

Zoom to Bounding Box

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541 
The code on this link only works because the raw code is displayed in an Iframe, click "open" from the page to display without an IFrame or click the link below:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4699541/

Zoom to Bounding Box II

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675
The code on this link only works because the raw code is displayed in an Iframe, click "open" from the page to display without an IFrame or click the link below:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/9656675/

Click-to-Zoom via Transform

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590
The code on this link only works because the raw code is displayed in an Iframe, click "open" from the page to display without an IFrame or click the link below:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/2206590/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following line:

> .attr("overflow", "hidden");

Below is where it needs to be placed:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("overflow", "hidden");
```